# Delete statement history

Tags: sql-server

I need to check which tables were deleted from production database. I've tried to use views  sys.dm_exec_cached_plans, sys.dm_exec_query_stats,sys.dm_exec_sql_text but I didn't find the answer. I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017, SQL 2012.

Comment: try sys.fn_dblog() function

Comment: How can I get to know the names of the tables which were dropped?

Comment: Do you have a backup to diff against?  [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) includes a tool that can help you with this.

Comment: Yes, backup is made every day. To be honest, I have never used SSDT but I'll find some information how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the dropped table names from the log. The only way to get the name is:

1. Get transaction id from fn_dblog

> ```
> SELECT 
>   [Transaction Id]
>   ,[Begin Time]
>   ,SUSER_SNAME ([Transaction SID]) AS [LoginName] 
> FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)  
> WHERE [Transaction Name] = N'DROPOBJ';
> ```

2. Get object_id:

> ```
> SELECT TOP 1 
>   [Lock Information] 
> FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)  
> WHERE [Transaction Id] = 'YOUR_TRANSACTION_ID'  
> AND [Lock Information] LIKE '%SCH_M OBJECT%';
> ```

And then restore the backup and check the object name from sys.objects